# Keras model with several inputs and several outputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to build a Keras model with two inputs and two outputs which both use the same architecture/weights. Both outputs are then used to compute a​ single loss.

Here is a picture of my desired architecture.

[image]

This is my pseudo code:

```
model = LeNet(inputs=[input1, input2, input3],outputs=[output1, output2, output3])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=my_custom_loss_function([output1,outpu2,output3],target)
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

Can this approach work?
Do I need to use a different Keras API?

Comment: This is documented well in the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) of Keras. You can find examples and explanation there on how to build such models.

Comment: I have read it but it's still not clear to me. I want to run input1 through the whole network get output1, then run input2 through the same network and get output2. Then at the end compute a combined loss. Could you provide a small code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The architecture is fine. Here is a toy example with training data of how it can be defined using keras' functional API:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input

# two separate inputs
in_1 = Input((10,10))
in_2 = Input((10,10))


# both inputs share these layers
dense_1 = Dense(10)
dense_2 = Dense(10)

# both inputs are passed through the layers
out_1 = dense_1(dense_2(in_1))
out_2 = dense_1(dense_2(in_2))

# create and compile the model
model = Model(inputs=[in_1, in_2], outputs=[out_1, out_2])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()

# train the model on some dummy data
import numpy as np

i_1 = np.random.rand(10, 10, 10)
i_2 = np.random.rand(10, 10, 10)

model.fit(x=[i_1, i_2], y=[i_1, i_2])
```

Edit given that you want to compute the losses together you can use `Concatenate()`

```
output = Concatenate()([out_1, out_2])
```

Any loss function you pass into `model.compile` will be applied to `output` in it's combined state. After you get the output from a prediction you can just split it back up into it's original state:

```
f = model.predict(...)

out_1, out_2 = f[:n], f[n:]
```

Comment: # create and compile the model
model = Model(inputs=[in_1, in_2], outputs=[out_1, out_2])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

How is the loss computed in your example? 
Are both outputs combined and evaluated with a single target? => This is what I need.

Comment: You can define a custom loss function but in this example mse is used. If you want to combine your targets you can also combine them inside your model using a `concatenate` and just output a single vector. Then you can split up that vector in whatever way to reconstruct the original outputs.